# SetText function in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, settext

I am trying to use setText function in netbeans. So there is a login page if the user login to the page with the correct credentials, (in this case that is only admin) in the next page (which is the main page) there should be a message with **Welcome User** 
I am trying to change the label to Welcome user in the main page

Backend of the login button

```
private void loginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
       if(loginUsername.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 && loginPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            int opt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "All fields are required", "Alert", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
        }
       else if((loginUsername.getText().toString().equals("admin") && loginPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin"))){
           new MainPage().setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
       }
       else{
           int opt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Username or Password Incorrect", "Alert", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
       }
    }
```

Code that i tried in the Main Page

```
SignUp signUp = new SignUp();
        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
        mainPage.setVisible(true);
       mainPage.jLabel2.setText("Welcome" + signUp.loginUsername.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use a MouseListener. You should add an `ActionListner` to the button on your login page. The `ActionListener` will be invoked when you click on your Login button.
2. The second block of code you posted should be in the `ActionListener` code of your login button.

So the code should be something like:

```
else if((loginUsername.getText().equals("admin") && loginPassword.getText().equals("admin")))
{
    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
    mainPage.jLabel2.setText("Welcome" + loginUsername.getText());
    mainPage.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you do you know a way to create a session in java netbeans like in php i have to make a table view. I don't know how to get the user id from the database. The database is sqlie. Do you happen to know this ?